# jQuery .detach() behaves inconsistently

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to implement some `<div>` reordering functionality while also swapping certain elements within the `<div>` at the same time.

I'm using jQuery's [`detach()`](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) to move elements around.  It performs as expected most of the time, but occasionally it seems as if the `detach()` doesn't occur.

Demonstrated in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/travisz/m2m9nqx6/34/)
- repeatedly click the `Move Up` or `Move Down` buttons for the issue to occur (it can take up to 10-15 times).

Am I missing some order of operations here that is occurring in the DOM?

Comment: I clicked more than 40 times and nothing wrong

Comment: i didn't see anything. what's the issue?

Comment: The `<th>` inside the `<div>` doesn't get swapped sometimes and the ordering becomes incorrect, the 'Tier 2' `<th>` appears incorrectly in the first `<div>` instead of second.  Happens for me in Chrome, Firefox and IE11.

Comment: works fine here too.

Comment: Try only clicking 'Move Down' in the first div in very quick succession.  The 'Tier 2' `th` will eventually appear incorrectly in the first div.  I've tested on two machines and am able to reproduce on both.  Sometimes it takes more clicks than other times though... seems like a race condition almost... stumped here.